# Can valid JSON file consist of only one single object's description?

Tags: javascript, json

Example of given JSON file is as follows:

```
result = {
    "name": "Foo",
    "id": "10001",
    "values": "1,2,3,4"
};
```

Comment: That isn't JSON.  That's a JS object literal.

Comment: And what does "single object description" mean in this context? The data type ?

Comment: @Adriani6 I wanted to say that mentioned code looks like a description of one object, named "result" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not valid JSON.

First, JSON is a string.  What you have in the question is a [JavaScript object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) expression assigned to the variable `result`.

Go to https://jsonlint.com/ , paste your file into the box, and click Validate.  You will see the following output:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
result = {  "name": 
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

As you can see from the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/) , you can't have a variable as a top-level entity.  The valid entities in a JSON string are:

- a string
- an object
- an array
- a number

Your `result` variable is not one of those things.  It's a variable, which is only valid in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
objLiteral = {
    "name": "Foo",
    "id": "10001",
    "values": "1,2,3,4"
};

jsonString = '{ "name": "Foo", "id": "10001", "values": "1,2,3,4" }';

var myObj = JSON.parse( jsonString );

console.log(objLiteral);
console.log(myObj);

console.log(objLiteral.name);
console.log(myObj.name);
```

```html
<pre>Sample javascript</pre>
```